# Область видимости переменных

Tags: c++builder, c++

Мне нужна передать значение с одного унита в другой.
В unit1 значение присваивается при нажатии на кнопку Button
А в unit2 нужна получить это значение при формировании формы(__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner));
Как это можно сделать?

Пробовал сделать так -- Пример:
Проект состоит из двух форм.

```
+++++++++ Содержимое Unit1.cpp +++++
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
int a;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
//a = 31;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
a = 73;
Form2->ShowModal();
//Form2 -> Close();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

+++++++++ Содержимое Unit2.cpp +++++
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit2.h"
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;
extern int a;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
 Label1->Caption = IntToStr(a);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 Label1->Caption = IntToStr(a);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

При компиляции проекта при нажатии на форме1 на кнопку Button запускается форма, в Label1 заносится 0 а не 73. А вот когда при нажатии на форме2 на кнопку Button в Label1 заносится уже нужное значение. А мне нужно чтобы это значение занести при запуске формы2.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить или подскажите другой метод. Пробувал обьявить класс что то не получилось.

Comment: @S-Nelsona, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В unit1.h в классе TForm1 определите переменную в секции public

```
public:     
    int a;
```

и дальше уже сможете к ней обратиться из второй формы таким образом:

```
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 Label1->Caption = IntToStr(Form1->a);
}
```

ЗЫ Примерно так и с Marker'ом поступайте из предыдущего вопроса.

Comment: Спосибо за ответ.
Зделал так, как вы написали, проблема не решилась.
Получается то что если присвоить переменной значение при событии(Button2Click) то это значение можно получить только при током событии на дугой форме.
То есть, если я на форме1 присвою переменной а = 5;в событии(Button2Click)  то это значение на форме2 я могу получить только при таком же событии(ButtonClick, BitBtnClick  и т.д) 

Код:
На форме1 я переменной а = 5;
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
a = 7;
}

Comment: Label2->Caption = IntToStr(Form1->a);
//По идее при запуске формы в Label2 должна было отразатся значнеие "5", но отражается "0" (пустая переменная)
}
//----
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Label2->Caption = IntToStr(Form1->a);
//А вот когда уже нажму на Button то В Label2 отражается значение "5"
}
//----
void __fastcall TForm2::BitBtn1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   Label2->Caption = IntToStr(Form1->a);
}

Надеюсь я понятно расписал проблему.

Comment: Сможете получить это значение при любом событии, которое будет по времени выполнения следовать за присвоением. Например ``Form2Show``.

    // Из первой формы вызываем вторую
    void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
    {
      a = 73;
      Form2->ShowModal();
    }

    // Во второй форме используем значение переменной из первой формы
    void __fastcall TForm2::Form2Show(TObject *Sender)
    {
      Label1->Caption = IntToStr(Form1->a);//73
    }

Comment: Следует заметить, что обращаться из одной формы в другую и из другой обратно в первую - не очень хорошая идея. Направление передачи и возврата значений по возможности стоит делать в одном направлении, т.е. если из Form1 открывается модальная Form2, то стоит сначала передать туда необходимые значения, а в зависимости от ModalResult формы Form2 забрать результат тоже в форме Form1:

Comment: Код:

    //Открываем вторую форму и устанавливаем необходимые начальные для нее значения
    void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
    {
      a = 73;
      Form2->Label1->Caption = IntToStr(a);
      if (Form2->ShowModal() == mrOK){
        ShowMessage(Form2->Label1->Caption);
      }
    }

    //Закрываем форму с результатом mrOK
    void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
    {
      Label1->Caption = "100500";
      ModalResult = mrOK;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за терпение.
Теперь помогло, когда поставил на событие

```
OnShow(void __fastcall TForm2::Form2Show(TObject *Sender))
```

как вы и написали. Это можно еще поставить на событие OnActivate.